# How can I add text or images along the lines of rows in a table?

Tags: html, css

I want it to look similar to the numbers in black circles on this MDN image.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Grid_Lines/1_diagram_numbered_grid_lines.png

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
table td {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 3px solid black; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand very much of your question
but I create a sample close to the image that u provide

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xL7r8wj9/6/)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
table td {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 3px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
table td > span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30%;
  left: 45%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><span>1</span></td>
      <td><span>2</span></td>
      <td><span>3</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>1</span></td>
      <td><span>2</span></td>
      <td><span>3</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>1</span></td>
      <td><span>2</span></td>
      <td><span>3</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Create a wrapping div, put image of grid in it with relative positioning, and put texts (divs) in it with absolute positioning, something like this: [How to absolutely position shape elements relative to an underlying image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848156/how-to-absolutely-position-shape-elements-relative-to-an-underlying-image)
2. Or you can use [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) and draw the entire thing yourself.

There are probably more ways to do it, but take a look at above for a start.